# Numpy Float128 Polyfit

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm using numpy's polyfit to find a best fit curve for a set of data. However, numpy's polyfit returns an array of float64 and because the calculated coefficients are so large/small (i.e. 1e-200), it's returning an overflow error that's encountered in multiply :

RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
  scale = NX.sqrt((lhs*lhs).sum(axis=0))

I've tried casting the initial array to be float128, but that does not seem to work. Is there any way around this overflow issue / any way to handle such large coefficients?

Comment: What degree are you specifying?

Comment: Fairly large - I had it set for 75 to try to minimize the oscillations in the best fit curve. One of the data sets I have resembles a guassian curve, but with polyfit set to deg = 45, the error goes away, but the best fit curve oscillates quite a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

You may use logarithmic version of your variables (`np.log10`), so when dealing with something like 1e-200 you will have -200, less memory and more efficiency.

Comment: It's not actually the variables I'm passing in - it's the best fit line that np.polyfit produces that is causing the issue, I believe. My actual data is well within the limits of float64. If I trace the error, it's being produced in the call to polyfit